# Populate Word document from collection of Range

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

In my Word addin I have a list of Range copy from Document.Words collection like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
    List<Range> list = new List<Range>();
    foreach (Range word in doc.Words)
    { 
        list.Add(word);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("list: " + list[0].Text + "|"+ list[1].Text + "|"+ list[2].Text + "|"+      list[3].Text + "|"+ list[4].Text);

    list[0].Text = "Hello ";
    MessageBox.Show("list: " + list[0].Text + "|"+ list[1].Text + "|"+ list[2].Text + "|"+ list[3].Text + "|"+ list[4].Text);
}
```

Now I create a document containing "good good good.". After assign first item in list to "hello", the second item change too. The message show a list with "Hello ", "hello good " (???), "good". So what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to the list not a reference to Range but its value (text):

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach (Range range in doc.Words)
{ 
    list.Add(range.Text);
}
```

or shortly:

```
var list = new List<string>(doc.Words.Cast<Range>().Select(r => r.Text));
```

So now you can manipulate strings without referencing VSTO objects.

Comment: Wouldn't the `list[0].Text` effectively do the same thing?

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Should definitely. But OP runs in some difficulties still, so I'm proposing a sort of workaround to go away from VSTO objects (I'm not sure in their behavior).

Comment: Thanks, that works correct now. Can you explain more about what happen in the code I post ?Is it wrong because I add the reference of the Range object ?

Comment: @Husky: Hard to say without the full code. I think something is wrong with referencing to ranges when you manipulate documents, ranges, their values, etc.

Comment: Actually that's all the code.i created a C# word add-in, add a ribbon to it, then add a button to ribbon.Click the button will call the function contain the code.I just add the full function to question